# How to change welcome text in Magento 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, html

I'm trying to change the color of the welcome text, and I have found the place( Configure-design) to change the actual text, but no way to change the color. Any ideas about where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing color of welcome text from backend is not possible, you need to define in theme css file.

If you are using custom theme, some custom theme provide option to write custom css in backend also. you can use that option also to write css in custom theme.

Comment: So I have found the css file that will change attributes for this bar everywhere else, but the changes still won't affect the welcome text.For example the text attributes on my about me page will change, while on my home page is still the default. Any ideas?